# The plugin command has been renamed

Tags: geolocation, cordova-plugins, ionic3

After installing Ionic last version 3.1.2 I tried to add the Native Geolocation plugin and I got the following:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
```

The plugin command has been renamed. To find out more, run:

```
ionic cordova plugin --help
```

I will appreciate any help on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/plugin/), the command for [ionic cli version 3](https://blog.ionic.io/announcing-ionic-cli-v3/) is:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
```